# Wordpress. How to add a js script? (hosted at wordpress.com)

Tags: wordpress, wordpress.com

I have a wordpress blog hosted at **wordpress.com** and I was trying to add a custom js script. What would be the simplest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I know, you are not allowed to add custom JavaScript code to your blog. Wordpress.com won't let you for security reasons.

Source: [Wordpress Support](http://en.support.wordpress.com/code/#javascript)